# Monte Carlo on Cuda

Tags: c++, cuda

I have tried to write a program which calculates pi for the arbitrary generated N numbers.

```
   __global__ void kernel(int* count_d, float* randomnums, double N){
      int i;
      double x, y, z;
      //Find the overall ID of the thread
      int tid = blockDim.x*blockIdx.x+threadIdx.x;
      i = tid;
      int xidx=0;
      int yidx=0;


      //Start the MonteCarlo
      xidx = i + i;
      yidx = xidx +1;


      //Get the random x,y points 
        x = randomnums[xidx];
        y = randomnums[yidx];
        z = ((x*x) + (y*y));

      if (z<=1)
        count_d[tid] = 1;
      else
        count_d[tid] = 0;
    }



    int main(){

      double N = 100000;
      float *randomnums;
      double pi;


      //Threads per thread block to be launched
      int threads = 1024;
      //Number of thread blocks launched
      int blocks = 100;
      int* count_d;

      unsigned int reducedcount = 0;

      for (int i=threads*blocks; i<=N; i+=threads*blocks){

      //Allocate the array for the random numbers
      cudaMalloc((void**)&randomnums,(i)*sizeof(float));
      //Use CuRand to generate an array of random numbers on the device
      int status;
      curandGenerator_t gen;
      status = curandCreateGenerator(&gen, CURAND_RNG_PSEUDO_MRG32K3A);
      status |= curandSetPseudoRandomGeneratorSeed(gen, 4294967296ULL^time(NULL));
      status |= curandGenerateUniform(gen, randomnums, (i));
      status |= curandDestroyGenerator(gen);

      //Check to see if there was any problem launching the CURAND kernels and generating
      //the random numbers on the device
      if (status != CURAND_STATUS_SUCCESS){
        printf("CuRand Failure\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
      }

        int *count = (int*)malloc(blocks*threads*sizeof(int));
        unsigned int reducedcount = 0;
        //Allocate the array to hold a value (1,0) whether the point in is the circle (1) or not (0)
        cudaMalloc((void**)&count_d, (blocks*threads)*sizeof(int));

        kernel <<<blocks, threads>>> (count_d, randomnums, i);

        cudaDeviceSynchronize();
        cudaMemcpy(count, count_d, blocks*threads*sizeof(int),cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);


        //Reduce array into int
        for(int j = 0; j<N; j++){
           reducedcount += count[j];
        }

        //Free the cudaMalloc()'d arrays
        cudaFree(randomnums);
        cudaFree(count_d);
        free(count);
     }
      //Find the ratio
      pi = ((double)reducedcount/N)*4.0;
      printf("Pi: %f\n", pi);

      return
 0;
}
```

I came up with an idea to split N into parts with the block*thread size and lunch the kernel for each part. It turns out that when I increase the N variable, I am getting the segmentation error: `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`.Why is that happening? 
Also I would like to ask if my idea with lunching a kernel in a loop is right.

Comment: Why N is double? Cant it be unsigned int? I am not saying this fill fix the issue. Better check whether memory allocation is successful whenever you allocate something. I guess when you increase N, you will be allocating more memory and some allocation is failing.

Comment: @MayurK `size_t` would be the most appropriate type in my eyes...

Comment: After using malloc, you should check the result for being `nullptr` (`NULL`, if C), if allocation fails, you get a such one. Neither do you check the result of `cudaMalloc`.

Comment: @Aconcagua What is a syntax for checking results for being nullptr?

Comment: @Monica `if(!pointer)` (with pointers, just as with integers, any value != 0, or != nullptr, evaluates to `true`; `!` negates this result to get the opposite), alternatively `if(pointer == nullptr)`.

Comment: Your `//Reduce array into int` loop is executing illegal memory accesses because of an incorrect loop trip count. [SO] isn't a free debugging and mistake spotting service. Please don't treat it like one -- learn to use a source debugger instead.

Comment: @talonmies I am new to CUDA and appreciate any help and tips how to teach myself using debuggers. I still struggle with finding simple bugs. I had found the mistake and corrected it. Though I am still wondering if it is working right. I'd expect a better approximation of pi with that number of points. I am getting: Number of points 804528840, Pi: 3.142691; Number of points 804346271, Pi: 3.141978. That does not look right to me. Am I am still doing something wrong?

Comment: Hey, if you like my answer please accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be doing a lot of manual memory management. That's bad, and leads to bugs and hard to read code. Consider this code where `thrust::device_vector` is used instead of raw pointers.

```
#include <curand.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <cuda_runtime.h>
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
#include <chrono>
//Pulls in library in MSVC
#pragma comment(lib, "curand.lib")

struct hypot_add {
//using float2 so may as well get twice the values, for memory throughput reasons you might find that float4 or some larger structure gives better performance
    __host__ __device__ float2 operator()(float2 &input) const {
        const auto a = hypot(input.x, input.y);
        const auto b = hypot(input.y, input.x);
        return float2{ a,b };
    }
};
struct float2_add
{
    __host__ __device__ float2 operator()(float2 &a, float2 &b) const {
        return float2{ a.x + b.x, a.y+b.y};
    }
};
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    const auto samples = 1024 * 1024*8;
    thrust::device_vector<float2> values(samples);
    curandGenerator_t gpu_generator;
    curandCreateGenerator(&gpu_generator, CURAND_RNG_PSEUDO_DEFAULT);
    const auto seed = std::chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch().count();
    curandSetPseudoRandomGeneratorSeed(gpu_generator, seed);
    {
        auto values_ptr = thrust::raw_pointer_cast(values.data());
        curandGenerateUniform(gpu_generator, reinterpret_cast<float*>(values_ptr), 2 * values.size());
    }
    // Notice that the number of blocks and threads is automatically determined
    thrust::transform(values.begin(), values.end(), values.begin(), hypot_add());
    const auto sum = thrust::reduce(values.begin(), values.end(), float2{ 0,0 }, float2_add());
    std::cout << 2*(sum.x+sum.y) / samples << std::endl;
}
```